# Create primary key / foreign key relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am setting up some very simple test tables and would like to make the column `USERKEY` the primary key of my table `tb_TestUSERS` then make the column `USERKEY` the foreign key in the table `tb_TestFACT`. Then set up a relationship between this primary key and foreign key. I'd like to be able to do all of this using scripts.

So far I just have the basic table scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE WH.dbo.tb_TestFACT
(DATEKEY INT,USERKEY INT);
INSERT INTO WH.dbo.tb_TestFACT
    values
    (1,1),
    (2,1),
    (3,2),
    (4,2),
    (5,2),
    (6,3),
    (7,3);

CREATE TABLE WH.dbo.tb_TestUSERS
(USERKEY INT,NAME VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO WH.dbo.tb_TestUSERS
    values
    (1,'FRED'),
    (2,'PHIL'),
    (3,'JACKO');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tb_TestUSERS
(
    UserKey INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (UserKey),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Name)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE tb_TestFACT
(
    UserKey INT NOT NULL,
    DateKey INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (UserKey)
        REFERENCES tb_TestUSERS(UserKey),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq1 UNIQUE (UserKey, DateKey) 
)
GO
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9536c/1)

Comment: +1 @J_W are the lines `CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Name)` and `CONSTRAINT tb_uq1 UNIQUE (UserKey, DateKey) ` essential? I realise duplicate names would be strange but is this constrainst essential?

Comment: `CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Name)` you can remove that if you want user to have the same name. `CONSTRAINT tb_uq1 UNIQUE (UserKey, DateKey)` will enforce a `UserKey` can have only unique `DateKey`.

Comment: thanks - might leave that off aswell as in the bigger picture a user might have lots of sessions on the same day - thanks for including these extra CONTRAINT scripts though as I will make wide use of them in production schema.

Comment: ...so your example demonstrates the three possible keys that can be applied in sql-server? Primary/Foreign/Unique? That also being the order of their "strength"?

Comment: @JohnWoo; Thanks a lot. A clear explanation on how to make relation

Answer (score 1):

If you have `SQL Server Management Studio` or `SQL Server Management Studio Express` then you can actually get it to do it for you.  Alternatively, you can do this in the UI and get it to script it to a new window - all very useful facilities.